# How can I use Boost Test with Boost Units

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test, boost-units

I expected this to compile properly:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/units/quantity.hpp>
#include <boost/units/systems/angle/degrees.hpp>

using boost::units::quantity;
using boost::units::degree::degrees;
using boost::units::degree::plane_angle;

int main() {
    quantity<plane_angle> q1 = 15 * degrees;

    BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(q1, 15 * degrees, 1e-8);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately this produces a couple hundreds lines of errors with GCC.

Of course I could do this instead.

```
BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(q1.value(), 15, 1e-8);
```

But I would like to keep the units explicit in the test case, just in case that someone else decides to change the unit type of `q1`.

Is there any way to keep the unit explicit?

Comment: `15 * degrees` doesn't have the type you expect, try using `15.*degrees`.

Comment: I have had the same problem. BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL and BOOST_CHECK_LT etc... work but not CLOSE. It appears to be something like boost converting the values to integers in order to do the tolerance check

Answer (score 0):

One option is to divide the equal values and compare to 1:

BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(q1 / (15 * degrees), 1, 1e-8);

When dividing boost::units::quantity by the same type, you end up with a dimensionless quantity, which is allows to be implicitly cast to double.